# error when use CommentsResponse callback from android market api on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, session, eclipse-plugin, google-play

I use android market api at link:https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Here is my code to get some comment of user on market:

```
MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
    CommentsRequest commentsRequest = CommentsRequest.newBuilder()
            .setAppId("7065399193137006744").setStartIndex(0)
            .setEntriesCount(10).build();
    session.append(commentsRequest,
            new Callback<Market.CommentsResponse>() {

                public void onResult(ResponseContext arg0,
                        CommentsResponse arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    session.flush();
```

and eclipse alert error at "new Callback() ": **The type Request.Callback is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments**
and i change to new Callback but has same error. So, anybody can give me a solution?Sory for my bad english,thanks.

Comment: somebody can help me?

Comment: how u fix it same prob i m facing